# 'adb pm hide' returns permission exception

Tags: adb, miui

Trying to hide security app since its deletion causes a softbrick.

'pm hide package.name' returns:

> Exception occurred while executing 'hide':
> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.

And some following lines of java errors.
Tried also: 'pm hide --user 0'
Tested the 'hide' command on several packages.
The phone is not rooted yet but perhaps su would do? I mean 'su pm hide'. This is MIUI global 12.5.5 on Redmi 9.

I want to hide security app to prevent kids from accessing Second Space.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a seconary account and give that to your kids. Or, use a kiosk (parental control sort of) app to limit access to settings app.

Comment: Thanks Firelord, I actually switched Launcher to an external password protected which allows to just hide the security app icon. Still wondering about the hide command, however. Have read your 'identity crisis' thread but still no answer for the sort of error my adb returns. Perhaps, hide command is discontinued or so?